# No Skill Point Amulet

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get the amulet to win a battle on row 8 with no skill points used? Which field to use?  Do you still use the YOL trap strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without skills you can only place one tower with one level 1 gem. With this its hard to kill even the first wave. 
Use the field C8, create a tower near mana shards. The tower should kill few monsters from first wave and before the rest comes (build walls so the monsters have the longest path to your tower) you should have harvested enough mana to upgrade the first gem. When you can afford it build the second tower that can help kill monsters and harvest other mana shards. When you clear one from four mana shards in a group build a tower on the cleared spot. That gives you four towers which will harvest all of mana and should kill all the monsters. Watch out for the giants - focus on one gem for maximum damage, the rest is only for swarm waves.

YOL strategy requires to much mana - I used pure Lime. You could mix in just a little blue for extra damage but use of slow is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

On B8,

- use level one poison gems (g1) in every trap
- start new waves as soon as the waiting monsters (counter between brackets) drops to 0 to gather extra mana.
- Upgrade gems once all traps are in use.